# Уместно ли здесь использовать точку с запятой?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, точка-с-запятой

*...которые заставляют её думать: «Я – человек; я – животное; я – царь; я болен; я голоден; я унижен; я щедрый; я – муж; я – жена; я – отец; я – сын; я – враг; я –друг; я – учёный; я красивый; я богат; я беден; я счастлив; я несчастлив; я сильный; я слабый».*

Answer (score 2):

Вполне уместно. Точка с запятой — более сильный разделительный знак, чем просто запятая, поэтому если автор хочет подчеркнуть "разделение" элементов перечисления, то использует точку с запятой.
Розенталь пишет:

> Сопоставим два предложения:
>
> *Был тихий мороз, заря догорала, высоко лежали пуховые снега* (Пан.);
>
> *Полки ряды свои сомкнули; в кустах рассыпались стрелки; катятся ядра, свищут пули; нависли хладные штыки* (П.).
>
> В подобных случаях возможна вариативность употребления запятой и точки
> с запятой.